# Endless while loop while polling data out of received bytes

Tags: c#, sockets, while-loop

I use some third party code from which i thought it worked...it is a loop which is polling some data out of the received Socket-bytes with a ByteBuffer and has to react to the timeout in case when the NetworkTpdu is null, but it doesn't! The while-loop is endless...Somebody an idea?

```
int start = Environment.TickCount;
int myTimeout = 5000; 
while (NetworkTpdu.CreateFromBuffer(_receiveBuffer, false) == null && (!_masterMode || Environment.TickCount - start < myTimeout))
{
    _receiveBuffer.WaitForByte(myTimeout, false);
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged it? Checked for the condition `Environment.TickCount - start < myTimeout` in a debugger when it should have timed out? Perhaps `_masterMode` is false? Perhaps `WaitForByte` is blocking indefinitely?

Comment: Environment.TickCount is millisecond (int) and 'myTimeout' also

Comment: In 5seconds it should have timed out, I debugged it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will probably be easier to find the problem if you split the method into separate statements. For example:

```
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        while (true)
        {
            var buffer = NetworkTpdu.CreateFromBuffer(_receiveBuffer, false);
            if (buffer != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Buffer is not null");
                return;
            }

            if (_masterMode)
            {
                if (sw.Elapsed > timeout)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Timeout!");
                    return;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Wait for byte: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            _receiveBuffer.WaitForByte(timeout.TotalMilliseconds, false);
            // Check if WaitForByte succeeded or timed out, and handle the result
        }
```

This should make it easy to find the problem:

1. Wait for Byte is not printed -> CreateFromBuffer never returns
2. Wait for Byte is only printed once -> WaitForByte never returns
3. Wait for Byte is printed with a value over 5000 -> _masterMode is false

Edit: As canton7 mentioned in the comments, you can do the same thing with a debugger by placing breakpoints or tracepoints at appropriate places. This is merely a way to make the execution order more apparent.

Comment: Note that you can do exactly the same using a debugger, without having to change the code. If you're not comfortable using the debugger however, this is going to be a better way to go